# Vertical align elements (universal solution) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, vertical-alignment

I am attempting to have a cross browser solution for vertical alignment of an element (it has been documented so many times that I'm not sure where to attribute it). It works great except for when using Chrome where the element contains an image. This is because Chrome determines the height of the image is 0 because it hasn't loaded it yet I believe. How do I modify the below jQuery to fix this?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".valign").vAlign();
});


(function ($) {
  $.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){

        var ah = $(this).height();
        var ph = $(this).parent().height();
        var mh = Math.ceil((ph - ah) / 2);
        if (mh < 0) {
            mh=0;
        }
        $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `$(document).ready()` with `$(window).load()`.  It won't execute until all the referenced images load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the targeted image first and use the callback to trick the height calc.  So:

```
...return this.each(function(i){
    $('targetImagePlaceholder').load('image/url.jpg', function(){
        var ah = $this.height():
        ...
```

Should work for ya.

Comment: this works but is not generic enough. i would like to use this in multiple situations, and i won't necessary know what the link is to the S3 bucket where the image is stored. also, there are situations where there are multiple imgs inside the element that i would like to vertically align. don't want to have to go inside each one.

Comment: ya i noticed that after i answered, but wanted to get a response first,  since you are calling $(this) anyway, you can use $(this).load to do each one, but I also have to ask what you are loading that you wont know the src for.